# Playn: Cannot successfully deploy Android profile for any Playn demo

Tags: android, plugins, maven, playn

I seem to have successfully installed playn, its samples, and built a skeleton app, both in eclipse, and with maven.  Everything works for Java or HTML builds.  Unfortunately, I cannot deploy to android: every time I try to do so, I get:

```
mvn -e android:Deploy
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Reactor build order: 
[INFO]   PlayN Showcase Metaproject
[INFO]   PlayN Showcase Core
[INFO]   PlayN Showcase Java
[INFO]   PlayN Showcase HTML
[INFO]   PlayN Showcase Android
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'android'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-android-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried deleting the ~/.m2/repository/com/jayway/maven/plugins/android/generation2/android-maven-plugin/3.0.0-alpha-13 directory and that seems to make no difference (though maven will pull it back down successfully each time).  Also if I do a mvn clean on the entire project, the android component builds along with everything else.  So the problem seems constrained entirely to "deploy."  Stumped...

Answer (score 4):

As you can see from error report, Maven is trying to resolve the plugin using the default group `org.apache.maven.plugins`, which is wrong in your case. You need to specify the group explicitly:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-alpha-13</version>
</plugin>
```

If it still fails, specify the following in your `~/.m2/settings.xml`:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>
```

Comment: Thank you!  You got it in one!  For anyone else who hits this, the offending file was: ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-android-plugin/maven-metadata-central.xml